# Setting up Gurobi with Python

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to use `Gurobi` in `Python`. As an IDE, I use `PyCharm`. When I use to install `gurobipy` through `PyCharm`, I receive the following error.

[image]

I also tried to install the library via `Anaconda` as shown at [this link](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044290292-Installing-Gurobi-for-Python). However, I receive another error shown below.

```
(base) C:\Users\...>conda install -c gurobi gurobi
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - gurobi -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

I have the academic version of `Gurobi 9.0.2` and use `Python 3.8.3` in `Windows 10`. I was wondering how I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to comment but it appears as though the version of python that you are using is incompatible with the gurobipy library/package. You may wish to create a new conda environment using Python 3.7 and attempt to download the gurobipy library onto that conda environment. Here is a reference for doing this https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: I did what you suggested. I crated an environment using python 3.7 and installed gurobi via it. My question is how I am going to use this in my project now.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that it worked. You can "use" the environment by invoking (here assume the environment is named py_env): "conda activate py_env" in your terminal session. If you are using an IDE, such as VS Code or PyCharm, I can't give specific advice without knowing the type but generally they allow you to select the environment when you choose the version of python that you use.

Comment: In PyCharm, I go to the terminal session and first call ``conda create -n myenv gurobi``. I can see that ``gurobi`` is downloaded as a library. Then, I invoke ``conda activate myenv`` as you suggested. However, I still cannot use the library.